# problema con request.getparameter

Tags: java

Este es el código y me dice este error (ver la imagen), no se como utilizar para las variables `String`

Su ayuda por favor,

```
//si el boton es carrito
if (request.getParameter("bt_ok") != null) {

    Producto p = new Producto(request.getParameter("ddlb_p"),
            Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("tf_codigo")),
            String.valueOf(request.getParameter("tf_descripcion")),
            String.valueOf(request.getParameter("tf_Bodega")),
            Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("tf_existencia")),
            Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("tf_precio")),
            Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("tf_descuento")),
            Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("tf_medida")),
            String.valueOf(request.getParameter("tf_expiracion")),     
            Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("tf_lote")));
```

[image: Error]

Comment: Sin ver el código del constructor de la clase Producto no podemos decirte exactamente qué falla, pero le estás pasando parámetros incorrectos. El error te dice que el primer parámetro debería ser un int y estás pasando un String, además de que el número de parámetros es incorrecto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error es porque le estas pasando un parámetro de más al constructor de tu clase Producto. El prarámreo que parece sobrar es `request.getParameter("ddlb_p")`.

Tienes dos posibilidades:

Si necesitas el `request.getParameter("ddlb_p")` para crear un producto, ve al constructor de la clase Producto y añade que recive esta variable:

```
public producto(String ddlb_p, Int tf_codigo, String tf_descripcion, String tf_Bodega, Int tf_existencia, double tf_precio, double tf_descuento, double tf_medida, String tf_expiracion, Int tf_lote){}
```

O en caso de no necesitar cambiar el constructor, cambia la creación del Producto sin pasarle esta variable:

```
Producto p = new Producto(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("tf_codigo")),
            String.valueOf(request.getParameter("tf_descripcion")),
            String.valueOf(request.getParameter("tf_Bodega")),
            Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("tf_existencia")),
            Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("tf_precio")),
            Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("tf_descuento")),
            Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("tf_medida")),
            String.valueOf(request.getParameter("tf_expiracion")),     
            Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("tf_lote")));
```